# How to participate in a remote IEEE Conference, due to politics problems in my country?

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, ieee, video-conference

Today I study in Chile, and I have an accepted paper at an international conference of the IEEE of good level. I need that participation since it will help me in my Postgraduate program, but I'm afraid I will not be able to attend. It is unsafe to travel at the moment.

How could I ask the Chairs of the conference and convince them to pay registration and let me present by video-conference? Or if anyone has any idea how to justify my paper appearing in the proceedings of the conference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact the conference chair and/or the program chair of the conference as ask how you can proceed. For some conferences this will be possible, and I suspect that IEEE will support reasonable requests. Most large conferences will have the ability to project from remote sources.

To actually present, however, will require some infrastructure on your end, including some sort of video link (maybe just a web cam) and adequate band width for the link. It might even be possible for a prepared talk to be sent to them prior to the conference by digital media. But you can explore the possibilities with the PC or CC. But you need to do it early.

A third possibility is to have you not present at all, physically or virtually, but still have your paper appear in the proceedings.

Happily, digital solutions exist. Sadly political issues make some things hard.

Comment: There are, indeed, time where I think a band witch is necessary to get a video conference to actually work. Sadly, I usually end up with the wicked witches, not Glenda the Good... (I can't edit to change one character, but that typo did tweak my weird sense of humor.)

Comment: @JonCuster. Mine too. Thanks. Fixed. Patience, though, I'm older than dirt.

Comment: Do you know if there is an IEEE support email to help and address these issues?

Comment: Sorry, no. The conference website should be able to give you the information you need, though. The organizers are usually pretty visible people.

Comment: Thanks for all, in a few days, tell them how I was.